# not an accidental override in Kotlin

Tags: interface, kotlin

I have java interface

```
public interface LifecycleRegistryOwner extends LifecycleOwner {
@Override
LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle();
}
```

and Kotlin class that implements this interface, it would be super nice to have just

```
val lifecycle by lazy {
    val result = LifecycleRegistry(this)
    result
}
```

but compiler says it's an accidental override. is there way to tell it was made by intention?

my current implementation

```
class PartnerSettingsActivity :AppCompatActivity(),LifecycleRegistryOwner {
    private val registry = LifecycleRegistry(this) //<< hate this class-wide val
    override fun getLifecycle(): LifecycleRegistry = registry
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell Kotlin compiler to accept the risk of such "accidental override" because there would be conflicting constructs on the bytecode level. Neither you cannot use [@JvmName](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-jvm-name/) to modify the name of field generated in bytecode because it does not work with delegates, and lazy is a delegate.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to flag the override as intentional as you can do in c# or VB.  This is the first thing I've hit in Kotlin and it seems a half-baked language so far...